# С помощью чего автоматически собрать несколько css файлов в один файл со сжатием?

Tags: css

Есть сайт на вордпресс у которого много несжатых `css` файлов .
С помощью чего, автоматически собрать несколько `css` файлов в один файл со сжатием?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С помощью gulp или webpack например.

Comment: я думал gulp только для scss

Comment: это очень широкий инструмент, он и для js, и для шрифтов, и для изображений, и для html, и для less и sass и много чего он собирать может